# cp and mv if the file named already exists

Tags: files, rename, cp

What happens when you give the following commands if the file named done already exists?

```
$ cp to_do done
$ mv to_do done
```

Comment: It's copied (in case of `cp`) and replaced (in case of `mv`)!

Answer (score 8):

`done` will be replaced by the content of `to_do`

You can check with a simple test:

```
$ echo a > done
$ echo b > to_do
$ cp to_do done 
$ cat done
b
```

and

```
$ echo a > done
$ echo b > to_do
$ mv to_do done
$ cat done
b
```

**Edit**

Following the comments some additional info

- `done` will not be replaced if either `done` or `to_do` are directories. If `done` is a directory the file `to_do` will be moved/copied *in* the directory. If `to_do` is a directory you will get an error message
- using the `-i` option you can instruct `mv` and `cp` to warn when overwriting a file
- on some distributions `cp` and `mv` are an alias to `cp -i` and `mv -i` (especially for the root user)

Comment: `cp` and `mv` will refuse to replace a file with a directory. Also, you could mention the `-i `option.

Comment: @Graeme The OP specifically asked about a file

Comment: Yeah, the target file. But `to_do` could also be a directory, in which case `cp`/`mv` would not replace `done`.

Comment: It's worth noting that some distributions of Linux imply the -i option by default, so on some distributions you would be prompted whether or not you want to replace the destination file.

Comment: @JamesHebden I don't think the word *imply* is quite the correct…implication. They may *alias* the `-i` option by default.

Comment: @kojiro You're right of course.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that we're talking of regular files here, in the case of:

```
cp to_do done
```

If `done` is not writeable, you'll get an error message. Otherwise, the content of `to_do` will be copied *over* `done`. What that means is that `done` keeps the same inode, permissions, ownership, birth time. The `-p` (or `-a` in some implementations) would try and copy some of the attributes of `to_do`.

With:

```
cp -f to_do done
```

If you don't have write access to `done`, `cp` will first unlink `done` (which you'll be able to do as long as you've got write access to the current directory and the current directory doesn't have the `t` bit set) and create a new one. `cp` will try and copy as many of the attributes of `to_do`, like it would if `done` didn't exist beforehand.

With

```
mv to_do done
```

`to_do` is just renamed. It's only the current directory that is modified. If `done` existed before hand, it will be unlinked first.